# problems with noscript when scraping using go-colly

Tags: go, go-colly

so I'm making a scraping script from a website. when scraping text is successful, only when scraping the image fails. When I inspect element the code is still normal, but when I run the view source the image wrapping code changes to noscript. So I thought that was the case, maybe someone can help?

```
c.OnHTML(".postarea", func(h *colly.HTMLElement) {
        as := Image{}
        as.Name = h.ChildText(".headpost .entry-title")
        h.ForEach(".maincontent", func(i int, x *colly.HTMLElement) {
            ya := So{}
            ya.Url = x.ChildAttr("#readerarea img", "src")
            as.Image = append(as.Image, ya)
        })
        b, err := json.MarshalIndent(as, "", " ")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to serialize response:", err)
            return
        }
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write(b)
    })
    c.OnRequest(
```

and this is the sample html code.

```
<div id="readerarea"><noscript>
        <p><img loading="lazy"
                src="#" alt=""
                width="725" height="1024" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-72251" /><img loading="lazy"
                src="#" alt=""
                width="725" height="1024" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-72251" /><img loading="lazy"
                src="#" alt=""
                width="725" height="1024" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-72251" /><img loading="lazy"
                src="#" alt=""
                width="725" height="1024" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-72251" />
        </p>
    </noscript>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be some JavaScript on the page that updates this (the `<noscript>` section is for browsers without JavaScript). When you 'view source' you are seeing the raw HTML as delivered by the server; with 'Inspect Element' you see the DOM as it stands (i.e. after whatever script that updates this section has run).

Go-Colly does not run [JavaScript](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/issues/4) so you will need another approach. Options include looking at the JavaScript to see how it locates the images or using something like [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp) instead of go-colly.